# Thymeleaf email image not displayed

Tags: html, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I'm using Thymeleaf with Spring Boot.

I'm trying to send a mail with a html template.

The mail is ok, the variable thymeleaf in the template are replace it's perfect, but, my only one problem is that the image are not displayed. It's just like if the image doen't exist.

The html template and the image ( Picture.png ) are on the same folder.

In the template I have try these multiples tries :

```
<img src="Picture.png" />

<img src="@{Picture.png}" />

<img th:src="|cid:${imageName}|" />  // by passing the "Picture.png" in the imageName variable

<img th:src="@{Picture.png}" />
```

But nothing is working, I need help thanks !

Comment: Were you able to resolve it? Because I am facing similar issue.

Comment: Yes, I put that in my html file : '<img src="cid:imageName"/>'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answer my own question because I suceed to resolve the problem :

Just put like that `<img src="cid:imageName"/>` in the html file

Answer (score -1):

Checkout the Thymeleaf's documentation especially the part for [context-relative and server-relative url patterns](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/standardurlsyntax.html).

If your project root directory is called **myapp** and you deploy it into a Tomcat server, your application will probably be accessible as *http://localhost:8080/myapp*, and **myapp** will be the context name.

So assuming the folder containing both the image and the html is located at:

```
myapp/resource/assets/(html and Picture.png exists)
```

the correct code to dynamically fetch the image is:

```
<img src="resource/assets/Picture.png"                                   th:src="@{resource/assets/Picture.png}" />
```